# Modelica C++ templates

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Does `Modelica` have something equivalent to `C++` templates? I would like to build a class that would process an input of type `T`, but `T` would be known only when instantiating the class. I tried to pass the type as a parameter but it gives errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replaceable types/classes.

```
model M
  replaceable class C; // = some partial class if you need an interface constrainedby ...
  C c;
end M;

model Test
  M m1(redeclare class C = C1);
  M m2(redeclare class C = C2);
end Test;
```

See more in the Modelica Specification 4.5 Class declarations https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec32Revision2.pdf.